# Rationale in avoiding self in idiomatic Ruby

Tags: ruby

The [Ruby style guide by bbatsov](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-self-unless-required) advises against using `self` unless necessary. Here's two direct examples of what he means:

```
# bad
def ready?
  if self.last_reviewed_at > self.last_updated_at
    self.worker.update(self.content, self.options)
    self.status = :in_progress
  end
  self.status == :verified
end

# good
def ready?
  if last_reviewed_at > last_updated_at
    worker.update(content, options)
    self.status = :in_progress
  end
  status == :verified
end
```

Why does he make this recommendation? What are some problems that using `self` to denote references to the object's own methods might cause? (The only instance I have just witnessed is the requirement to NOT use self when calling a private method within an instance method).

Comment: just verbosity I guess

Comment: I figured that also, but I wonder if it isn't more helpful to put `self` for the purposes of code maintenance. In areas of huge chunks of code, it may be easier to know when the method belongs to the object without having to hunt for the context; it seems more expressive to me to use it rather than not.

Comment: I agree, use `self` to be clear. I wouldn't use it for methods that I'm calling with arguments, I would use `self` for bare property references. It's a style thing.

Comment: I find the code a lot clearer and easier to read when the receiver is explicitly specified so I say `self.method` except when `method` is private. I find that leaving `self` out tends to make the human work harder to keep track of context, that may lead to pretty and poetic code but it doesn't make it more readable or maintainable.

Comment: I think you will get used to it if you practice it. Why you may ask? Imagine you get used to parsing `self`-less code then then your code will look less verbose. Its an advantage, since its reduced cognitive load.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is in large part about elegance, a big part of which is readability. Unnecessary qualifiers are syntactic noise which get in the way of that.

The example illustrates how `self` is unnecessary in all but the assignment case, where Ruby would create a local variable with the name `status` if it had not been qualified. By using the form `self.status=`, it is clear to Ruby that you want to invoke the `status=` method on `self`.